# How to wait for an element to be visible without erroring out?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I want to wait for an element to be visible, and if it is do X without erroring it out. I trying using the nightwatch.js waitForElementVisible but that errors out if the element is not visible. What should I do?

Comment: more detail please, i really dont get the point. Sample code would help!

Answer (score 0):

`waitForElementVisible` takes a param `abortOnFailure` to control if command should fail or not

http://nightwatchjs.org/api#waitForElementVisible

Comment: Be careful - `abortOnFailure` set to false actually still fails (does say `on failure` after all), it just does not cause an abort of the test suite if you have Nightwatch set to abort. It will still log as failed.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround is to use the function below, but the drawback is that we are setting static timeout,

```js
client.pause(1500).element('css selector', '.css_selector', result => {
  if (result.status > -1) {
    browser.expect.element('.element_to_check').text.to.contain('YES')
  }
})
```

This way nigtwatch will check your element and won't throw an error if it's not in DOM.